# Creating an abstract class to get perimeter and area?

Tags: java

The problem I was given:

Write an abstract superclass encapsulating a shape: a shape has 2 abstract methods: one returning the perimeter of the shape, another returning the area of the shoe. It also has a constant field named PI. This class has two non-abstract subclasses: one encapsulating a circle, and the other encapsulating a rectangle. A circle has one additional attribute, its radius. A rectangle has 2 additional attributes, its width and height. You also need to include a client class to test these two classes.

Here's the work I've done:

Shape.java

```
public abstract class Shape 
{

public abstract double getPerimeter();
public abstract double getArea();

}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle extends Shape 
{
private double radius;
final double pi = Math.PI;

//Defualt Constructor, calls Shape default constructor
public Circle() 
{
    //Set default value to radius
    this.radius = 1;
}   

public Circle(double radius) 
{
    this.radius = radius;
}

public double getArea() 
{
    //Return πr^2 (area formula)
    //Use Math.pow method (page 141) in order to calculate exponent
    return (pi * Math.pow(radius, 2));
}

public double getPerimeter() 
{
    //Return 2πr (perimeter formula)
    return (2 * pi * radius);
}}
```

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle extends Shape 
{
private double width, height; 
public Rectangle() 
{
    //set default value to width and height
    this.width = 1;
    this.height = 1;
}
public Rectangle(double width, double height) 
{
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public double getArea() 
{
    return width * height;
}

public double getPerimeter() 
{
    return 2 * (width + height);
}}
```

ShapeClient.java

```
public class ShapeClient {
public static void main(String [] args) 
{

    // To test Rectangle...
    double width = 13, length = 9;
    Shape rectangle = new Rectangle(width, length);
    System.out.println("The rectangle width is: " + width 
            + " and the length is: " + length
            + "The area is: " + rectangle.getArea()
            + "and the perimeter is: " + rectangle.getPerimeter() + ".");

    //To test Circle...
    double radius = 3;
    Shape circle = new Circle(radius);
    System.out.println("The radius of the circle is: " + radius
        + "The area is: " + circle.getArea()
        + "and the perimeter is: " + circle.getPerimeter() + ".");


}}
```

My question is: Does the constant field for PI need to be in the Shape class rather than the Circle class? If so, how should I about taking it out of the circle class and how should I place it in the Shape class?

Comment: You can make public static final int PI = 3.17 in your Abstract class if you want. As you should be declaring all the constants in your Parent class. But its just School project and you are never going to declare more of the shapes which use PI value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The abstract class should only contain fields & methods that are general to all shapes such as `getArea` and `getPerimeter`.

In this case `PI` is only specific to the `Circle` shape or to rephrase, the square has no use for the constant `PI`. `PI` should therefore only reside in the 'Circle' class and not the `Shape` class.

Answer (score 1):

The PI attribute definitely needs to be on the Circle class. The abstract Shape class should contain attributes and methods that all of its sub-classes are going to use or implement. In this case, the Rectangle class has no need for the PI attribute.

Answer (score 0):

just move the constant to the abstract class.